# Detect website attack by using azure sentinel serviceazure

Tags: azure, ddos, brute-force-attacks, attacks, azure-sentinel

I have a website which builds on AKS. I'm getting DDoS and other kind of attacks in website. In order to take prevention against such attacks, I'm planning to use the tool Azure Sentinel service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/hunting#use-the-hunting-dashboard

How to store streaming website traffic in AZure and integrate with azure + aler when unusual traffic hit occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Tried Sentinel service.